# Find Cov$\big(\hat{\beta_0},\hat{\beta_1}\big)$.

Tags: statistics, least-squares, linear-regression

The least squares estimator of $\beta_0$ is given as $\hat{\beta_0}=\overline{Y}-\hat{\beta_1}\overline{X}$. Find Cov
$\big(\hat{\beta_0},\hat{\beta_1}\big)$. When is Cov $\big(\hat{\beta_0},\hat{\beta_1}\big)=0$?

I'm not sure how to solve this. I started out by plugging in $\hat{\beta_0}$ into the Covariance to try and solve for $\hat\beta_1$. Can anyone help me out with this??

Comment: You should know that the variance matrix is $\sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}$. Just do the explicit computation and inversion of your 2x2 matrix and pick the bottom left (or top right) element in the matrix.

Comment: That would give me the Cov of that??

Comment: @Maffred would you be able to show me how you would do it?

Comment: The matrix of the variances is 2x2 with respectively the variance of $\beta_0$, the covariance, the covariance, and the variance of $\beta_1$. Since the matrix is $X'=111111/x_1\cdots x_n$ you get $X'X=n$ / $\sum x_i$ / $\sum x_i$ / $\sum x_i^2$. Invert it with the formula used to invert 2x2 matrices, don't forget then to multiply by $\sigma^2$.

Comment: @Maffred Is there a way to find the Cov($\hat\beta_0, \hat\beta_1$) without using matrices?

Comment: see if this helps https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788574/find-operatornamecov-hat-beta-0-hat-beta-1?rq=1

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123481/are-the-estimates-of-the-intercept-and-slope-in-simple-linear-regression-indepen?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104704/are-estimates-of-regression-coefficients-uncorrelated